# Auto adjusting form using margin

Tags: html, css

I'm using margins for my form but when I am testing the responsive layout the distance between the navigation bar increases if the screen width is a greater size. Therefore, I have also tried auto height but it still has a big gap between the navigation bar and the form.

I have also tried @media screen.

I had help yesterday with a similar problem to this, but now I'm encountering another one as its not with the footer but with the form itself.

I would kindly like to ask for help, and if you find a solution explain the changes so I can also learn from it! Kindest regards, Caelan : ).

```css
 body {
        background-color: black;
      }

      /* Announcment bar */
      .alert {
        padding: 20px;
        background-color: #2a7a85;
        color: white;
      }

      .closebtn {
        margin-left: 15px;
        color: white;
        font-weight: bold;
        float: right;
        font-size: 22px;
        line-height: 20px;
        cursor: pointer;
        transition: 0.3s;
      }

      .closebtn:hover {
        color: black;
      }

      body {
        margin: 0;
      }

      /* Navigation bar */
      ul.topnav {
        list-style-type: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
        background-color: rgb(248, 248, 248);
      }

      ul.topnav li {
        float: left;
      }

      ul.topnav li a {
        display: block;
        color: black;
        text-align: center;
        font-weight: bold;
        padding: 25px 32px;
        text-decoration: none;
      }

      ul.topnav li a:hover:not(.active) {
        background-color: rgb(55, 81, 165);
      }

      ul.topnav li a.active {
        background-color: #0cc0d8;
      }

      ul.topnav li.right {
        float: right;
      }

      @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
        ul.topnav li.right,
        ul.topnav li {
          float: none;
        }
      }

      /* On smaller screens, decrease text size */

      @media only screen and (max-width: 300px) {
        .text {
          font-size: 11px;
        }
      }

      /* Homepage button */
      .glow-on-hover {
        width: 220px;
        height: 35px;
        border: none;
        outline: none;
        color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 20px;
        background: #111;
        cursor: pointer;
        position: relative;

        z-index: 0;
        border-radius: 10px;
      }

      .glow-on-hover:before {
        content: "";
        background: linear-gradient(
          45deg,
          #ff0000,
          #ff7300,
          #fffb00,
          #48ff00,
          #00ffd5,
          #002bff,
          #7a00ff,
          #ff00c8,
          #ff0000
        );
        position: absolute;
        top: -2px;
        left: -2px;
        background-size: 400%;
        z-index: -1;
        filter: blur(5px);
        width: calc(100% + 4px);
        height: calc(100% + 4px);
        animation: glowing 20s linear infinite;
        opacity: 0;
        transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
        border-radius: 10px;
      }

      .glow-on-hover:active {
        color: #000;
      }

      .glow-on-hover:active:after {
        background: transparent;
      }

      .glow-on-hover:hover:before {
        opacity: 1;
      }

      .glow-on-hover:after {
        z-index: -1;
        content: "";
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background: rgb(11, 78, 223);
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        border-radius: 10px;
      }

      @keyframes glowing {
        0% {
          background-position: 0 0;
        }
        50% {
          background-position: 400% 0;
        }
        100% {
          background-position: 0 0;
        }
      }

      /* kipplo heading on homepage */

      h1 {
        font-size: 10vw;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        font-family: "Courier New", Courier, monospace;
        color: blue;
        word-wrap: break-word;
        text-align: center;
      }

      /* for the heading and the button alignment*/

      .container {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        height: 100vh;
      }

      .btn-centering {
        flex-grow: 1;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
      }

      /* product cards*/

      h3 {
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 30px;
        margin: 0;
        padding-top: 10px;
      }
      a {
        text-decoration: none;
      }
      .gallery {
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        width: 100%;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        margin: 50px 0;
      }
      .content {
        width: 24%;
        margin: 15px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        float: left;
        text-align: center;
        border-radius: 10px;
        border-top-right-radius: 10px;
        border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
        padding-top: 10px;
        box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
        transition: 0.4s;
        background-color: whitesmoke;
      }
      .content:hover {
        box-shadow: 0 0 11px rgb(0, 217, 255);
        transform: translate(0px, -8px);
        transition: 0.6s;
      }
      .productcard-image {
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
        text-align: center;
        margin: 0 auto;
        display: block;
      }
      p {
        text-align: center;
        color: #b2bec3;
        padding: 0 8px;
      }
      h6 {
        font-size: 26px;
        text-align: center;
        color: #222f3e;
        margin: 0;
      }
      .product-card {
        list-style-type: none;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        padding: 0px;
      }
      .productcard-list {
        padding: 5px;
      }
      .fa {
        color: #ff9f43;
        font-size: 26px;
        transition: 0.4s;
      }
      .fa:hover {
        transform: scale(1.3);
        transition: 0.6s;
      }
      .productcardbutton {
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 24px;
        color: #fff;
        width: 100%;
        padding: 15px;
        border: 0px;
        outline: none;
        cursor: pointer;
        margin-top: 5px;
        border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
        border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
      }
      .buy-1 {
        background-color: #2183a2;
      }
      .buy-2 {
        background-color: #3b3e6e;
      }
      .buy-3 {
        background-color: #0b0b0b;
      }
      @media (max-width: 1000px) {
        .content {
          width: 46%;
        }
      }
      @media (max-width: 750px) {
        .content {
          width: 100%;
        }
      }

      /* Footer */
      .footer__container {
        background-color: #141414;
        padding: 5rem 0;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
      }

      #footer__logo {
        color: #fff;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        cursor: pointer;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-size: 2rem;
      }

      .footer__links {
        width: 100%;
        max-width: 1000px;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
      }

      .footer__link--wrapper {
        display: flex;
      }

      .footer__link--items {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: flex-start;
        margin: 16px;
        text-align: left;
        width: 160px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
      }

      .footer__link--items h2 {
        margin-bottom: 16px;
      }

      .footer__link--items > h2 {
        color: #fff;
      }

      .footer__link--items a {
        color: #fff;
        text-decoration: none;
        margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
      }

      .footer__link--items a:hover {
        color: #e9e9e9;
        transition: 0.3s ease-out;
      }

      /* Social Icons */
      .social__icon--link {
        color: #fff;
        font-size: 24px;
      }

      .social__media {
        max-width: 1000px;
        width: 100%;
      }

      .social__media--wrap {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        align-items: center;
        width: 90%;
        max-width: 1000px;
        margin: 40px auto 0 auto;
      }

      .website__rights {
        color: #fff;
      }

      @media screen and (max-width: 820px) {
        .footer__links {
          padding-top: 2rem;
        }

        #footer__logo {
          margin-bottom: 2rem;
        }

        .website__rights {
          padding: 2rem;
        }

        .footer__link--wrapper {
          flex-direction: column;
        }

        .social__media--wrap {
          flex-direction: column;
        }
      }

      @media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
        .footer__link--items {
          margin: 0;
          padding: 10px;
          width: 100%;
        }
      }
      /* Text above the form*/

      /* Feedback form*/

      .form1 {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
        width: 500px;
        margin: 15vh auto;
        margin-top: -200px;
        height: auto;
        border-radius: 15px;
        border: none;
        box-shadow: 0 0 15px rgb(24, 143, 190);
      }

      form {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
        width: 90%;
      }

      input {
        width: 100%;
        margin: 5px 0;
        height: 35px;
        font-size: 17px;
        text-align: center;
        outline: none;
        border-radius: 15px;
        border: none;
        background: rgb(235, 228, 228);
      }

      textarea {
        width: 100%;
        margin: 5px 0;
        font-size: 17px;
        text-align: center;
        outline: none;
        border-radius: 15px;
        border: none;
        background: rgb(235, 228, 228);
      }
      input[type="submit"] {
        margin: 10px auto;
        width: 120px;
        background: rgb(24, 143, 190);
        color: white;
        cursor: pointer;
      }
      input[type="submit"]:hover {
        background: rgb(19, 41, 238);
      }
      @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
        .form1 {
          width: 90%;
          margin-top:-250px;
          height: auto;
        }
      }

      h2 {
        color: #00ffd5;
        font-size: 30px;
      }

      p4 {
        color: #00ffd5;
        font-size: 20px;
      }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="icon" href="img/icon.png" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
    <title>Contact Us</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- Alert bar -->
    <div class="container">
      <div class="alert">
        <span
          class="closebtn"
          onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none';"
          >&times;</span
        >
        <center>
          <strong>DEALS NOW ON!</strong> Upto 30% discounts this christmas
        </center>
      </div>
      <!-- Navigation bar -->
      <ul class="topnav">
        <li><img src="img/logo.png" /></li>
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="products.html">Products</a></li>
        <li><a class="active" href="contactus.html">Contact Us</a></li>
        <li class="right"><a href="#about">About Us</a></li>
      </ul>
</div>
      <!-- Form -->
      
      

      <div class="form1">
        <h2>Contact Us!</h2>
        <p4>Typical Replies Within 24hrs!</p4>
        <br />
        <form action="">
          <input
            type="email"
            name="email"
            id="email"
            placeholder="Enter your email"
          />
          <input
            type="text"
            name="name"
            id="name"
            placeholder=" Enter your name"
          />
          <textarea
            name="message"
            id="message"
            cols="30"
            rows="10"
            placeholder="Enter your message here"
          ></textarea>
          <input type="submit" value="Send" />
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Footer -->

    <div class="footer__container">
      <div class="footer__links">
        <div class="footer__link--wrapper">
          <div class="footer__link--items">
            <a href="/sign__up">About Us</a>
          </div>
          <div class="footer__link--items">
            <a href="/">Contact Us</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="footer__link--wrapper">
          <div class="footer__link--items">
            <a href="/">Youtube</a>
          </div>
          <div class="footer__link--items">
            <a href="/">TikTok</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <section class="social__media">
        <div class="social__media--wrap">
          <div class="footer__logo">
            <a href="index.html">
              <img src="img/logo2.png" id="footer__logo"
            /></a>
          </div>
          <p class="website__rights">
            &copy; KIPPLO.CO.UK PROTOTYPE 2022. All rights reserved
          </p>
          <div class="social__icons"></div>
        </div>
      </[![section][1]][1]>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I analyzed your code. You have just to remove the `height: 100vh` from your `.container`.

The next step is to remove the `margin-top: -250px` from your `.form1`. then it should look good.

Bonus Tip: the unit `vh` stands for viewport-height (browser height). so 100vh is 100% of the viewport height.

Comment: This helped significantly, I now have a better understanding! Thank you very much for also taking the time out of your day to help me understand and fix my problem. I highly appreciate it, Regards Caelan.